Trying to get a property by key using either main or child object
I have an interface, greatly simplified for brevity:
 interface Author {
       id?: number;
       firstName?: string;
       lastname?: string;
       age?: number;
       coAuthors?:
       [
         {
            id: number;
            firstName: string;
            lastname: string;
            age: number;
         }
       ]
    }

Trying here to get an object value by key:
 const getByKeyName = <T extends {coAuthors: ['coAuthors']}, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K) =>
    {

        return item[key] ?? (item.coAuthors?.length ? item.coAuthors![0][key] : 0);  
    };                                                              ^^^^^^^^^  
                                                                    cannot use [key] to index item.coAuthors![0] 

  -----------------------------                     
  getByKeyName(author, 'id');

This results in the TS error above, because child is a different object. What's best to implement that?

What does interface Author have to do with getByKeyName?

@Bergi author is an instance of interface Author.

Ah, but the error is in the definition not in the call of the function, right? Either way, it looks like {coAuthors: ['coAuthors']} is not really what you want.

The error is in on a line I highlighted, not definition.

Isn't that line in the definition of the function?

That's in a return statement.

Does an approach like this meet your needs?

@jsejcksn PartialParentWithChildren and Expand seem unnecessarily complicated, no?

@jsejksn Looks great but overly complicated for what I need - I'd rather not touch any of the existing types, like answer below.

^ @Bergi The Expand* types are there only to help IntelliSense reveal expanded type info on hover (not related to the QA). The PartialParentWithChildren utility type could be inlined, but it's there to clarify the relationship within the data structure described in the question.

^ @Victor I have reservations about the accuracy of the type in your question, but if it's not a concern to you, then you can simplify it this way. Does that fully satisfy the requirements of the question? If so, I can write an answer. If not — what did I miss?

@jsejskn Never mind the type, it's way more elaborate, just greatly simplified for clarity. This looks exactly what I need. Only minor detail - in your last example need to return 0 or empty string instead of undefined. But I can handle that on a caller side as well.

You can type the function to accept a generic type parameter K which is constrained by a union of keys common to the parent author and first co-author — then use a combination of nullish coalescing (??) and optional chaining (?.) to return the first value found in either the parent or first child:
TS Playground
function getByKeyName<K extends keyof Omit<Author, "coAuthors">>(
  author: Author,
  key: K,
): Author[K] | undefined {
  return author[key] ?? author.coAuthors?.[0][key];
}


Update: In a comment you said:

[I] need to return 0 or empty string instead of undefined. But I can handle that on a caller side as well.

That's exactly right: you can use nullish coalescing at the call site to use a default value in case of an undefined result:
TS Playground
const id0 = getByKeyName(author, "id");
//    ^? const id0: number | undefined

const id1 = getByKeyName(author, "id") ?? 0;
//    ^? const id1: number

const id2 = getByKeyName(author, "id") ?? "";
//    ^? const id2: number | string

